# The fastests way to copy to and from Texture2D

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, directx-11

For some reason I have to copy from textures to buffer and then reload it back to the texture.
The source texture is the one coming from decoder, target texture is the one which will be rendered. The easiest way to do that (as I understand) is to do the following:

1. decoder tex(`ID3D11Texture2D`)
2. Use temp texture (`Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING`)
3. `CopyResource` to temp texture
4. 'Map'
5. `memcpy`_s to buffer
6. `Unmap`

on the other side it goes backward

1. Use temp texture (`Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING`)
2. `Map`
3. `memcpy_s` from buffer
4. `Unmap`
5. `CopyResource` to renderer texture

Works fine, however I have a feeling I'm not doing it as efficient as possible (aside the fact I'm copying data back and forth)
Do I have to use staging textures? Can I tweak the decoder/renderer texture flags (BindFlags?) or the Map's D3D11_MAP enumeration to skip copying to staging texture?

EDIT001:
Ok, here goes the case, with technical details. There is a decoder, essentially it is Intel Media SDK decoder which decodes (pun intended) data provided from outside the decoding class. So, it receives a buffer, does its magic(asynchronously) and returns (by means of SyncOperation, If I recall the method name right) a surface, which is actually, under the hood DX texture, managed by the Intel allocator. I receive and copy the texture synchronously, but I guess, with a little effort I can do it asynchronously. The surface originates from a pool, so, working with the texture does not stops the decoder to keep the work on. The copied data resides in a struct which is kept in ring buffer, from which the video renderer is fed. That's it, to my understanding (a little one, I have to notice) there is no harm to the GPU parallelism.

Comment: Wait, are you doing any CPU processing over the texture ? If not, you can just `CopyResource` between the two GPU texture, no need for a staging temporary.

Comment: nope, all processing done using Intel Media SDK, decoding and VPP, only the final result is copied to renderer (via cyclic buffer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have to read and write back, there is no fast way, you break GPU/CPU parallelism by forcing sync point and you will create many idle bubbles on the CPU and GPU.

Only the staging pool is accessible to the CPU, so yes, the temporary resource for the back and forth is necessary.

For performance, you should consider :

1. Adapt your technique to be GPU only
2. If read back is the only way, limit to portion that are dirty or neccessary
3. Try to work with a couple of texture accross frame to let the CPU work on a version that is a few frame behind to protect parallelism.

Comment: Aha... stuff getting clear... I have a couple of things to point out. First, in this particular case we are talking about Intel GPU, the one on-die, so, I guess (as I understand how the stuff works) there is no too much overhead since Intel GPU is not discreet card, it doesn't have its own memory, so, all copying is on the same memory and goes via the same memory manager as CPU stuff goes. Am I correct?

Comment: Second, your statement "the temporary resource for the back and forth is necessary", which is clear, but how many temporaries I need? at this moment I have 3 resources (2 temp textures and one buffer) which gives me 4 copies. all of them are necessary? And the last but not least, point 3, what do you mean by " texture accross frame to let the CPU work on a version that is a few frame behind to protect parallelism"

Comment: Even on an intel integrated chip using the main memory, there is different memory access type ( cached/uncached/write combined ) plus potential hidden swizzling and tiling, and the D3D11 API is not designed to let you know anything of the internals, so yes, you have to keep the 3.

Comment: For parallelism and performance, the gpu run a few frames behind, if you read back and wait for the result, you destroy any chance of performance. Depending on what you want to achieve ( you should describe your original problem, not the problem you have on your supposed solution ), you may be able to tolerate latency of a few frame over the read back result or change things to not need a sync point anymore. That is the only way.